# undefined local variable or method after eval when not declared before

Tags: ruby, eval

In Ruby

```
2.1.2 :068 >   a=1
 => 1
2.1.2 :069 > eval("a=4")
 => 4
2.1.2 :070 > a
 => 4
2.1.2 :071 > eval("b=4")
 => 4
2.1.2 :072 > b
NameError: undefined local variable or method `b' for main:Object
```

So,the question is why the variable 'b' will be 'undefined local variable or method' but the variable 'a' equals 4  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the `eval` lambda you create a new scope for the code that you execute.

It would be like to create and execute a new lambda. If you declare `a` before and then use a variable called `a` in your lambda, you shall use the same. But if you don't declare `b` before the lambda, `eval` will create its own variable, and will delete it at the end.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ there is no notion of “function” in ruby. The above is correct for procs/lambdas and wrong for methods.

Comment: In short: local variables really *are* local, that's why they are called *local*. In this case, `b` is local to the `eval`'d code.

Answer (score 1):

```
 puts "outside binding #{binding.__id__}"
 a = 1
 puts "outside a #{a.__id__}"
 eval 'b="b"; puts "inside binding #{binding.__id__}"; puts "inside a #{binding.local_variable_get(:a).__id__}"; a="c"; puts "inside after a #{a.__id__}"'
 puts "outside after a #{a.__id__}"
```

run the code above, you can see that the outside binding and the inside binding is using different ids. but share the same a. when we run eval, ruby will copy the outside binding, so it will use the same a; but b is defined in the inside binding, when eval is done, inside binding is lost and so is b. Actually block scope is same as this.